# An Equality of Some Two Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given domain of discourse D,

Suppose $A \subset D,$ that is $A$ is a proper subset of $D.$

Let $S =$ {$x \in D:$ $x \in A$}

Any element of $x$ of $S$ satisfies: $x \in D$ and $x \in A. \; (S \subseteq A)$

Any element of $x$ of $A$ satisfies: $x \in A$ and $x \in D. \; (A \subseteq S)$

It seems to me that necessarily and trivially so,
$$S=A$$

Would be great if you could comment if my conclusion is right.

Comment: Yes, $S=A$ by the definition of $S$.

Comment: @GregMartin besides definition, subset method was fine too?